# Long math expression in R

Tags: r, math, expression, mathematical-expressions

It's my first time here and I'm not really practical, but I hope my question will be clear and I'll find the right answer.
I'm trying to calculate a vowel space area (a phonetic measure for vowels) in R: that requires a long math expression.
Here's what I wrote and the type of error I had back:

> tVSA<-(0.5 * ((F2U_patients + F2I_patients) * (F1U_patients - F1I_patients) – (F2A_patients + F2U_patients) * (F1A_patients - F1U_patients) – F2A_patients + F2I_patients) * (F1A_patients - F1I_patients))

Error: unexpected input in "tVSA<-(0.5 * ((F2U_patients + F2I_patients) * (F1U_patients - F1I_patients) –"

What could it be? Obvoiusly each of those names (F2U_patients etc.) corresponds to objects I already defined in R. To me, it also looks like each pair of brackets has been righly opened and closed. I also tried with [] too. Could someone help me find me problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have two kinds of minus signs (hyphens) in this expression. The long one is not correct, probably.

Comment: I agree. When I replace the dashes with minus signs and assign values to the objects, it works.